# How to fill a secured PDF from spreadsheet data [Java]

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox, fdf

I have looked into two libraries for doing this to no success. I am not the most experienced.

PDFBox - I think because it is a secured pdf the PDDocument class was unable to load the fields to fill.
Adobe FDFToolkit - I couldn't get the fields from the file because it was a PDF not an FDF. Not sure how to convert.
iText - org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1OctetString error while opening the PDF

I am having trouble getting any of these to work due to the nature of the file. It is a government immigration form which can be found here: https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-589.pdf. Any ideas for working around this?

Comment: You should know what you want to do. Create a PDF that looks like an excel file? Or assign specific fields from an excel file to a PDF with form fields (acroform)? Re acroform, PDFBox has examples in the source code download.

Comment: Why did you tag your question with itext if you didn't try with iText?

Comment: I am trying to use iText currently. I was aware it was similar.

Comment: I edited my original post for a bit more clarification. The problem I am having is filling a secured PDF, specifically an i-589 form. It can be downloaded here: https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-589.pdf.

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried?

Comment: You haven't posted the full error, but I suspect this would help: http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-do-i-get-bouncycastle-noclassdeffounderror or enter "itext bouncycastle" into google. I suspect the BC jars are missing. (PDFBox needs them too, it is described on the website: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html )

Answer (score 0):

Your form is encrypted using an owner password. The permissions are set in such a way that they allow form filling, but iText nor PdfBox are currently fine-grained enough to check those permissions: if a PDF is encrypted, you are asked to provide a password.

However, with iText, there is a setting called `unethicalreading`. See [How to decrypt a PDF document with the owner password?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-decrypt-pdf-document-owner-password) in the official documentation:

```
PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
```

By setting this static variable to `true`, the PDF will be treated as if it weren't encrypted.